# If an atom is put into motion will a constituent electron's wave spread over a LARGER region of space and will its energy be more dissipated?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

My understanding is that a quantum event such as an electron moving between atomic levels takes place smoothly and continuously over a small discrete time interval during which time its energy will be relatively unstable.

Also an electron can spread out into a wave that extends over a region of space.

If an atom is put into motion will the electron's wave spread over a LARGER region of space than when stationary resulting in less energy per unit volume of space?

Comment: The electron **wave** is a **probability wave** . any wave natue will be found in distributions , as in the single electron double slit..https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles

Comment: @anna v The electron behaves physically as a wave as well as its effect being calculable as a probability wave.

Comment: Not in mainstream physics quantum mechanics theories.  It is only the probability that "waves".  That is what "orbitals" mean. https://physicsworld.com/a/quantum-microscope-peers-into-the-hydrogen-atom/

Comment: @anna v as far as I can tell there is no real consensus as to whether an electron (which certainly displays wave like properties) is physically a wave and/or a particle. If not a wave how would one explain interference patterns? Assuming that you are thinking of an electron only as a charged particle within an atom would you expect the effect of its charge to be distributed over a larger area when the atom is put in motion than when the atom is stationary?

Comment: It is not a matter of consensus, it is the theories based on quantum mechanics, with its strict postulates ,not a matter of voting. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html

Comment: @anna v  the development of QM is based upon the observations that "Early in the 20th century, electrons were shown to have wave properties, and the wave-particle duality became a part of our understanding of nature". The wave function is a mathematical function that can give us the probability of for example finding a particle in a given location but it does not provide us a description of the underlying reality.  Are you able to answer my original question assuming the electron to be a QM particle rather than a wave and considering the effect of the electron over a volume of space ?

Answer (score 0):

One does not really have to put atom in motion, but simply look at it from a moving (inertial) reference frame - with the same effect.

In fact, an atom consists of several particles: the nucleus and the electron(s). Just as in classical mechanics, one can decompose their motion into the motion of the center-of-mass of the atom and the relative motion of the particles in respect to each other. When treating the Hydrogen atom good quantum mechanics books usually explicitly spell this step, although it may get easily forgotten among all the complexities of solving the Schrödinger equation (for the relative motion!), the atomic orbitals, selection rules, etc.

Comment: so what in your view is the answer to the actual question?

Comment: If an atom is simply moving with a constant velocity, the relative motion of the nucleus and electrons will not change (apart from relativistic effects, if you look from another reference frame). If it is accelerated, then many things can happen, but for this your question is not precise. You may want to check [*Bremsstrahlung*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung)

Comment: What I am getting at is the effect of an electron moving between atomic levels once the atom is in uniform motion compared to its effect when it was relatively stationary. Whether we consider the electron as a particle or a wave or both the effect of it moving between atomic levels will be felt over a volume of space V1 for the stationary atom and a volume of space V1 + V2 for the atom in uniform motion. The energy of the event which takes place over a finite period of time will be dissipated over a greater volume of space for the atom in motion.